# Create a function that call methods in a class in typescript

Tags: typescript

normally class method call like

```
classA.method1(args)
```

But I want to make it a function which takes methodName and arguments to pass in and return the method result.

```
const function = (methodName, args = []) => {
  return classA[methodName](...args);
}
```

there are errors in the above code.

At the end I want to do something like:

```
function(methodName, [args])
```

to call classA's methodName method and return the result

How to write it in typescript? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you start in the right way. The example below is not very typesafe since there is some casting to `any`

```
class classA {
  static methodA1() {
    console.log('A1')
  }

  static methodA2(arg: string) {
    console.log(`A2: ${arg}`)
  }
}

const executeFunc = (funcName: string, args: any[] = []) => {
  return (classA as any)[funcName](...args)
}

executeFunc('methodA1')
executeFunc('methodA2', ['input argument!'])
```

I have a `classA` class with two methods that I can call in `executeFunc`